# How do you Highlight text programmatically in Word from Excel with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to generate a .docx report utilizing data created in Excel. The macro is running from excel, opens a word document, and inserts some sentences. I need a sentence in Word to be highlighted Yellow.

Here is what I currently have:

```
Set BreakDown = wrdApp.Selection
With BreakDown
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
    .TypeText (BreakDownText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
End With
```

The code:

```
.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
```

Does turn on highlighting but it sets the color equal to wdColorBlack

This was my starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845467(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: `wdColorYellow` is a Word constant, and Excel VBA doesn't automatically know what its value is.  You need to either add a reference to the Word object library in your Excel VBA project, or use the value instead of the constant name (as suggested by Tinbendr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the actual value of wdColorYellow.

```
 .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 65535
```